# stopping animations based on setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that I use to animate the filling out of a form.  Basically like a tutorial to show customers what and how to enter their information.  I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on what I could use to pause my animations.  For example a have a button that when clicked would pause the animation and when clicked again would continue the animation.

My animation is basically several setTimeout's inside of each other.

Example

```
setTimeout(function(){

$('#box1').val("1");

setTimeout(function(){


$('#box2').val("2");

setTimeout()....... and so on

},2000);


},200);
```

any ideas would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
myVar=setInterval(yourfunc(),2000);
```

for pause use:

```
cleartInterval(myVar);
```

you can check my func here: http://jsfiddle.net/YSfpm/

Comment: Could you explain what this does.  Thanks

Comment: It will pause your animation and again start with the same point when you click on start.

Comment: Does setinterval run forever?  Also I have several settimeouts inside of each other would i make my outer most timeout the variable? Or is myfunc() the function that has all the timeouts inside of it?

Comment: please try.after setInterval setTimeout works or not.Ihave no clean idea.

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure but maybe you can use

```
$("#box1").stop(true).hide('fast');
```

**OR**

```
setTimeout(function(){ $("#box1").hide(); }, 3000);
```